# Access Data type mismatch of date in sql query

Tags: c#, sql, datetime, ms-access, oledb

I am trying to get a list of orders from my access database that were ordered between 2 dates.
this is my query:

```
"SELECT * FROM Orders WHERE OrderDate >= '#" + DateTime.Parse(txtDate.Text) + "#' AND OrderDate <= '#" + DateTime.Parse(txtEndDate.Text) + "#'";
```

the 2 textboxes recieve the dates directly from 2 ajax calendar extenders. i have already made sure that the first date is before the second, and i had made sure that the data inserted to the database was also inserted like '#"+date+"#', but i "still data type mismatch in query expression".
can anyone try and identify a problem with my query?

Comment: [SQL Injection alert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) - you should **not** concatenate together your SQL statements - use **parametrized queries** instead to avoid SQL injection - check out [Little Bobby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com/)

Comment: @Erel would you please show what is your txtDate.Text looks like, what is the value for it.

Comment: If the field type of OrderDate is Date, you would get this error.

Comment: @ArsenKhachaturyan the value for the txtDate.text changes based on the calendar extender's selected date, which is selected by the user

Comment: @OguzOzgul how can i do it then? my data field is date, and it is too late for me to change it. even if the data field is date, you should be able to make query expressions regarding it

Comment: @HansUp the exception still appears. "Data type mismatch in query expression"

Comment: @Erel what the `Date` look like after user's selecting? Can you adjust it to the specific format I've shown below and check?

Comment: I asked because you said the dates are  "inserted like '#"+date+"#'. Use a parameterized query with ? as placeholders for the parameters

Comment: @ArsenKhachaturyan the date is in the format dd/MM/yyyy

Comment: @Erel in the post below I've used the `yyyyMMdd` format for the SQL, which is considered to be the most unambiguous format for SQL Date. Could you please try that?

Comment: I can't. i am using a web service that requires the date at this format

Comment: @ArsenKhachaturyan: The ISO sequence must have separators in Access SQL, like `2020/04/20`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have data like this:

```cs
var txtDate = new { Text = "2020-08-01" };
var txtEndDate = new { Text = "2020-08-01" };
```

your query might look like this:

```cs
var fromDate = DateTime.ParseExact(txtDate.Text, "yyyy-MM-dd",
                                 CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).ToString("yyyMMdd");

var toDate = DateTime.ParseExact(txtEndDate.Text, "yyyy-MM-dd",
                             CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).ToString("yyyMMdd");

var query =
    $"SELECT * FROM Orders WHERE OrderDate>='{fromDate}' AND OrderDate<='{toDate}'";
```

or the last part can be:

```sql
var query =
    $"SELECT * FROM Orders WHERE OrderDate BETWEEN '{fromDate}' AND '{toDate}'";
```

Answer (score 0):

It is the *octothorpes* that are delimiters for date expressions, not *single quotes*. And the formatted text expression for a date value should be forced. Thus:

```cs
"SELECT * FROM Orders WHERE OrderDate >= #" + DateTime.Parse(txtDate.Text).ToString("yyyy'/'MM'/'dd") + "# AND OrderDate <= #" + DateTime.Parse(txtEndDate.Text).ToString("yyyy'/'MM'/'dd") + "#";
```

That said, look up how to run queries with parameters. It takes a few more code lines but is much easier to debug and get right.

Comment: Thanks, but it is still not working. the "data type mismatch" still appears

Comment: That’s because access requires the date string in the format mm/dd/yyyy. Go figure

Comment: @Ciarán: No, it's not because of that. It's more likely, that OrderDate is not DateTime.

Comment: You may be right. I was addressing this answer rather than the original question. It used to be the case that MS/Access requires date literals in the format #mm/dd/yyyyy# but I've just tested it and that's no longer true. My bad. It accepts yyyy/MM/dd just fine. It's been so long since I've used date literals in SQL (like maybe 20 years!) that it was probably access 97 or 2003.

Answer (score 0):

You should use a parameterized query for both security and for type safety

Access database queries use `?` as a placeholder for the parameters you pass.

```
OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand();

// I assume you have an oledb connection object and it is in open state
command.Connection = myConnection;
command.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM Orders WHERE OrderDate >= ? AND OrderDate <= ?";

// Please note that the name of the parameters are redundant and not used
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("StartDate", DateTime.Parse(txtDate.Text));
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("EndDate", DateTime.Parse(txtEndDate.Text));

// You can also use your data adatper. This is just an example
command.ExecuteReader();
```

Comment: If this doesn't work, OrderDate is not of data type DateTime.

Comment: @gustav Yes, the OP said: "@OguzOzgul how can i do it then? my data field is date, and it is too late for me to change it."

Comment: Date or DateTime is VBA and SQL for the same. Where is the table stored? Access, SQL Server?

Comment: Gustav, is this meant for the OP?

Comment: Yes, should have noted that.

Comment: It is in the title: Access data type mismatch

Comment: True. But the table could be attached via ODBC to another database. Everything else seems correct, so looking for the not so obvious.